# Pyspark filter where value is in another dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have two data frames. I need to filter one to only show values that are contained in the other.

table_a:

```
+---+----+
|AID| foo|
+---+----+
| 1 | bar|
| 2 | bar|
| 3 | bar|
| 4 | bar|
+---+----+
```

table_b:

```
+---+
|BID|
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
+---+
```

In the end I want to filter out what was in table_a to only the IDs that are in the table_b, like this:

```
+--+----+
|ID| foo|
+--+----+
| 1| bar|
| 2| bar|
+--+----+
```

Here is what I'm trying to do

```
result_table = table_a.filter(table_b.BID.contains(table_a.AID))
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. It looks like I'm getting ALL values.

NOTE: I can't add any other imports other than `pyspark.sql.functions import col`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the two tables and specify `how = 'left_semi'` 
A `left semi-join` returns values from the left side of the relation that has a match with the right.

```
result_table  = table_a.join(table_b, (table_a.AID == table_b.BID), \
                        how = "left_semi").drop("BID")

result_table.show()
+---+---+
|AID|foo|
+---+---+
|  1|bar|
|  2|bar|
+---+---+
```

Comment: That is probably the right answer, but I'm getting annoying error when I try that. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64456642/trying-to-join-tables-and-getting-resolved-attributes-columnname17-missing-f

Comment: I think there is some ambiguity in the column names. Try to rename columns before you make the join.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have duplicates or Multiple values in the second dataframe and you want to take only distinct values, below approach can be useful to tackle such use cases -

**Create the Dataframe**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,"bar"),(2,"bar"),(3,"bar"),(4,"bar")],[ "col1","col2"])
df_lookup = spark.createDataFrame([(1,1),(1,2)],[ "id","val"])
df.show(truncate=True)
df_lookup.show()
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1| bar|
|   2| bar|
|   3| bar|
|   4| bar|
+----+----+

+---+---+
| id|val|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  1|  2|
+---+---+
```

**get all the unique values of val column in dataframe two and take in a set/list variable**

```
df_lookup_var = df_lookup.groupBy("id").agg(F.collect_set("val").alias("val")).collect()[0][1][0]
print(df_lookup_var)
df = df.withColumn("case_col", F.when((F.col("col1").isin([1,2])), F.lit("1")).otherwise(F.lit("0")))
df = df.filter(F.col("case_col") == F.lit("1"))
df.show()
+----+----+--------+
|col1|col2|case_col|
+----+----+--------+
|   1| bar|       1|
|   2| bar|       1|
+----+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work too:

```
table_a.where( col(AID).isin(table_b.BID.tolist() ) )
```