# Trying to join tables and getting "Resolved attribute(s) columnName#17 missing from ..."

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to join two tables and getting a frustrating series of errors:

If I try this:

```
pop_table = mtrips.join(trips, (mtrips["DOLocationID"] == trips["PULocationID"]))
```

Then I get this error:

```
Resolved attribute(s) PULocationID#17 missing from PULocationID#2508,
```

---

If I try this:

```
pop_table = mtrips.join(trips, (col("DOLocationID") == col("PULocationID")))
```

I get this error:

```
"Reference 'DOLocationID' is ambiguous, could be: DOLocationID, DOLocationID.;"
```

---

If I try this:

```
pop_table = mtrips.join(trips, col("mtrips.DOLocationID") == col("trips.PULocationID"))
```

I get this error:

```
"cannot resolve '`mtrips.DOLocationID`' given input columns: [DOLocationID]
```

---

When I search on SO for these errors it seems like every post is telling me to try something that I've already tried and isn't working.

I don't know where to go from here. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14948) problem. There is some ambiguity in the names.

Are you deriving one of the dataframes from another one? In that case, use `withColumnRenamed()` to rename the 'join' columns in the second dataframe before you do the join operation.

Comment: That did that trick. Thanks again Cena, you are my hero.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty evidante that the issue with column name in both the dataframe.

**1. When you have all different columns in both the dataframe , expect join key column is same name in both DF, use this**

```
**`df = df.join(df_right, 'join_col_which_is_same_in_both_df', 'left')`**
```

**2. When your join column is different name in both the dataframe - This join will take both the column i.e col1 and col2 in the joined df**

```
**`df = df.join(df_right, df.col1 == df_right.col2, 'left')`**
```

Comment: I'm trying to join a different named column from each table. I tried what you said like this: `pop_table = mtrips.join(trips, mtrips.DOLocationID == trips.PULocationID, 'left')` but I'm still getting the `Resolved attribute(s) PULocationID#17 missing from PULocationID#2768`

Comment: This looks like a column name mismatch - Please check correctly once the second Dataframe column names ...